# getting rid of Hbase configuration deprecated warning

Tags: java, hbase

I'm  getting this error message in my log file `WARN hbase.HBaseConfiguration: instantiating HBaseConfiguration() is deprecated. Please use HBaseConfiguration#create() to construct a plain Configuration` how can I get rid of this?

My class extends Configured.class , and I'm instantiating configuration like this :

```
HBaseConfiguration hBaseConfiguration = new HBaseConfiguration(getConf());
```

Did anyone have the similar issue? how to fix it ?

**EDIT**

How can I get this version of HbaseConfiguration :

http://hbase.apache.org/docs/r0.89.20100726/xref/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/HBaseConfiguration.html

I downloaded the latest version from hbase web site(version 0.20.6) but the class is different from this one, its missing create() method and some other too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting the Javadoc:

> Instantinating HBaseConfiguration() is
>   deprecated. Please use
>   HBaseConfiguration#create(conf) to
>   construct a plain Configuration

Instead of doing:

```
HBaseConfiguration hBaseConfiguration = new HBaseConfiguration(getConf());
```

You should do:

```
Configuration configuration = HBaseConfiguration.create(getConf());
```

Comment: thank you, I can read, but I don't understand what they mean, can you give me an example if you understood this piece of javadoc.

Comment: I get this compile message now `The method create() is undefined for the type HBaseConfiguration`

Comment: What does getConf() return? create(...) expects a 'Configuration' object Could you post some code, I'm not sure what you're doing.

Comment: This is what getConf() does http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/conf/Configurable.html#getConf() , maybe I'm not using the latest jar, when looking inside http://hbase.apache.org/docs/r0.89.20100726/xref/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/HBaseConfiguration.html create() method is visible and in there (+1)

Comment: Weird... Make sure you are compiling and running against the same version. Anyway, you should be fine, just be aware that deprecated methods/constructors might be removed in later versions.

Comment: I cant find the getConf() function, which class should I invoke this function?